# Optimized number of rows that can be inserted at each dump insertion to DB2 using JDBC

Tags: python, sql, jdbc, db2

Using a JDBC connection, I have about 50 million rows to insert to DB2 from Python.
I initially tried to insert one row at a time, which resulted in a huge processing time lag.
Therefore, I made it to insert 1,000 rows at each attempt, which clearly made a faster processing time. However, I wonder if there is a clear guideline to do this type of insertion.
How does one find the dynamic optimization of batch size for making dump insertion without taking a long connection hold?

Comment: For volumes around 50 million rows, you should be using LOAD (instead of insert), which is the only sensible approach when performance is a prime consideration. You can load from a pre-created file, or you can load from a pipe.  Learn about all the considerations for LOAD (which is a command, it is not SQL) by studying the documentation for your Db2-server platform and discussing the pros and cons with experienced people.

Comment: load is the fastest, you can also use external tables https://www.tridex.org/wp-content/uploads/Db2ExternalTables_Tridex.pdf